# Error when running my application from a startup shortcut I created

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form. When form is opened, it will read a text file in folder : (Debug)\Data\text.txt and show on a textbox ... That's really a simple form.

After I set my form running at Startup up

I use the way to creat my program shortcut in Startup Folder .

```
private void creatShortcut()
    {            
        WshShell = new WshShellClass();

        IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut MyShortcut;            

        MyShortcut = (IWshRuntimeLibrary.IWshShortcut)WshShell.CreateShortcut(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup)+"\\FaceLogin.lnk");           

        MyShortcut.TargetPath = Application.ExecutablePath;

        MyShortcut.Description = "Face Login";

         MyShortcut.IconLocation = Application.StartupPath + @"\Data\camera.ico";

        MyShortcut.Save();  
    }
```

After I run my form. It created a shorcut in Startup folder successfully.
I restart my computer to test but It throws this Exception.

> Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Key\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\data\face.fac'.

This is my code to read face.fac

```
private void loadDuLieu()
    {
        FileStream fs = null;
        try
        {

            if (!File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\\data\\face.fac"))                   
                fs = File.Create(Application.StartupPath + "\\data\\face.fac");
            else                
                fs = File.OpenRead(Application.StartupPath + "\\data\\face.fac");

                BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();

                if (fs != null)                        
                    lstDSMat = (List<Face>)bf.Deserialize(fs);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (fs != null)
                fs.Close();
        }
    }
```

That means my program can't find "data\face.fac" at Startup folder. I dont't understand  because Startup folder have only my program shortcut and nothing else.

How can I solve this problem to run my Face Login program in Startup without that err ?

Comment: Does that file exist when you navigate to it through explorer?

Comment: What is the real path of the file?

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the `WorkingDirectory` for your application using this line:

```
MyShortcut.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

the problem is that when **not** setting the working directory the application looks for everything in the directory the shortcut exists in.